# Случайные ссылки

Tags: php, javascript

Что лучшее использовать для создания рандома? PHP(серверная сторона) или JavaScript(клиентская сторона)?

Comment: А вам зачем? :) Какая цель у этих ссылок в вашем случае?

Comment: Незнаю, просто с одним человеком поспорил. Я за JavaScript т.к думаю, если есть возможность, то лучше рандом выполнять на клиентской стороне, чтобы лишний раз не нагружать сервер.

Comment: Ваш подход имеет право на жизнь. Только мне кажется что это экономия на спичках. Вот, например, что-нибудь шифровать у клиента вместо сервера - это более серьезная разгрузка была бы

Answer (score 2):

Очень широкий вопрос. Смотря для чего вам это нужно. Если случайная строка имеет криптографическое значение - однозначно серверная сторона и, при возможности, использование железного генератора.

Если никаких требований нет - то без разницы (других требований кроме криптографической стойкости что-то не пришло на ум)